# Ограничение оперативной памяти, доступной для postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql

Есть задание в лабораторной работе - ограничение оперативной памяти, доступной для postgresql. После поисков по теме были найдены способы ограничения.

1. Изменение `shared_buffers` в `postgresql.conf`.
2. Использование `cgroups`.

   файл cgconfig.conf:

   ```
   mount {
       memory = /mnt/cgroup/memory;
   }

   group postgres {
       perm {
           admin {
               uid = root;
               gid = root;
           }
           task {
               uid = postgres;
               gid = postgres;
           }
       }
       memory {
           memory.limit_in_bytes = 256m;
           memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = 256m;
       }
   }
   ```

   файл cgrules.conf:

   *:postgres  memory  postgres/
3. Использование `systemctl set-property postgresql.service MemoryLimit=256M`.

Проблема - память не ограничивается. Сравнивал время выполнения запросов c mssql от одногруппников, время выполнения запросов с ограниченной памятью кардинально различаются.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что я мог сделать не так или что мог упустить.

Спасибо заранее!

P.S. На mssql писать и учить не хочу до последнего, ибо надо накатывать винду.

Comment: Данный вопрос закрыт.

Comment: количество оперативной памяти на скорость выполнения запроса никак не влияет.

Comment: в конфигурации pg есть еще (мак минимум) maintenance_work_mem

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, я не понял постановку задачи, но почему просто не использовать

```
ulimit -d <Предельный размер памяти>
```

?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/111710)

Comment: *Не является ответом на вопрос* - автор спросил, как установить лимит памяти.  Я ответил - как... В чём проблема ?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос должен быть исчерпывающим и развёрнутым. Гипотезы "почему не использовать что-то?" лучше высказывать в комментариях. Подобные ответы приемлемы в формате обычного форума, но у ru.SO иной формат. Ничего личного.

Comment: **лучше высказывать в комментариях** - понял.

Comment: Данный вариант пробовал, но забыл упомянуть. В итоге преподаватель принял так как было. Вопрос можно закрывать.